# Cannot reference an id because code not yet returned

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling to reference something on my webpage using this:

`new Chessboard(document.getElementById('board3')`

It is supposed to display the board, but instead I get this error:

> Error: container element is null

The first answer in this link says...

> This is most likely due to your script running before the page is loaded.

[Why my `<div id="terminal-container">` is null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41691717/why-my-div-id-terminal-container-is-null)

So, how do I get around this issue where I need to create the board but I cannot do that because the id is in the return portion of the code, and so it is not yet created. I tried adding it after the return () code, but that did nothing!

Any ideas?

```
export const MyPiece = props => {

  new Chessboard(document.getElementById('board3'), {
    position:
      'rn2k1r1/ppp1pp1p/3p2p1/5bn1/P7/2N2B2/1PPPPP2/2BNK1RR w Gkq - 4 11',
    orientation: COLOR.black,
  });

  return (
    <>
        <DialogContent dividers>
        <Typography paragraph="true">
          Some text
        </Typography>
        <Paper id="board3"></Paper>
      </DialogContent>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause `new Chessboard(...` run before `<Paper id="board3"></Paper>` is mounted. Try wrap it in the `useEffect`

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'

export const MyPiece = props => {

  useEffect(() => {
    new Chessboard(document.getElementById('board3'), {
      position:
      'rn2k1r1/ppp1pp1p/3p2p1/5bn1/P7/2N2B2/1PPPPP2/2BNK1RR w Gkq - 4 11',
      orientation: COLOR.black,
    });
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
        <DialogContent dividers>
        <Typography paragraph="true">
          Some text
        </Typography>
        <Paper id="board3"></Paper>
      </DialogContent>
    </>
  );
};
```

Or if you do not use react hooks, It could be

```
class MyPiece extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    new Chessboard(document.getElementById('board3'), {
       position:
       'rn2k1r1/ppp1pp1p/3p2p1/5bn1/P7/2N2B2/1PPPPP2/2BNK1RR w Gkq - 4 11',
       orientation: COLOR.black,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <DialogContent dividers>
        <Typography paragraph="true">
          Some text
        </Typography>
        <Paper id="board3"></Paper>
        </DialogContent>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, that was perfect! Thank you. Your solution was so far off my radar I would have never got there without your help. I tried it and bingo, worked first time. I thought I was in a catch-22 situation. This will be very useful in lots of my stuff. Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

This `document.getElementById('board3')` is executed before the first render. The node is not available jet. Also every time the component is updated this function will runs. I assume that you don't want that. I recommend you to move your code to `useEffect` block:

```
useEffect(()=> {
  new Chessboard(document.getElementById('board3'), {
    position:
      'rn2k1r1/ppp1pp1p/3p2p1/5bn1/P7/2N2B2/1PPPPP2/2BNK1RR w Gkq - 4 11',
    orientation: COLOR.black,
  });
}, []);
```

You can replace `document.getElementById('board3')` with useRef, It is the recommend way.

Comment: Also a great answer and the same as the other guys.